# Scala 3. Kind polymorphism and AnyKind type - any code example?

Tags: scala, types, scala-3, type-kinds, polykinds

Scala3 has support for "kind polymorphism". Docs also mention `AnyKind` type:

> AnyKind plays a special role in Scala's subtype system: It is a supertype of all other types no matter what their kind is.

Question:

- can anyone give a working code example how `AnyKind` generality is useful?

(surprisingly can't find any useful examples so far)

[docs](https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/reference/other-new-features/kind-polymorphism.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example the type member `MirroredType` of `scala.deriving.Mirror.Product`/`Mirror.Sum` is actually poly-kinded (although this is not written in the definition of `Mirror`/`Mirror.Sum`/`Mirror.Product`)

```
sealed trait Mirror:
  type MirroredMonoType
  type MirroredLabel <: String
  type MirroredElemLabels <: Tuple
```

https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/reference/contextual/derivation.html#mirror

The type member `MirroredMonoType` has always kind `*`, including being [existential](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74267610/polymorphic-method-works-with-type-lambda-but-not-with-type-wildcard-in-scala-3) (`A[?]`). But `MirroredType` can be `*`

```
sealed trait A
case class B() extends A
case class C() extends A

val m = summon[Mirror.Sum { type MirroredType = A }]

//scala.deriving.Mirror.Sum{
//  MirroredMonoType = A; MirroredType = A; 
//    MirroredLabel = ("A" : String)
//  ; MirroredElemTypes = (B, C); 
//    MirroredElemLabels = (("B" : String), ("C" : String))
//}
```

or `* => *`

```
sealed trait A[T]
case class B() extends A[Int]
case class C() extends A[String]

val m = summon[Mirror.Sum { type MirroredType[T] = A[T] }]
//val m = summon[Mirror.Sum { type MirroredType = [T] =>> A[T] }]

//scala.deriving.Mirror.Sum{
//  MirroredMonoType = A[?]; MirroredType[T] = A[T]; 
//    MirroredLabel = ("A" : String)
//  ; MirroredElemTypes[T] = (B, C); 
//    MirroredElemLabels = (("B" : String), ("C" : String))
//}
```

etc.

Notice that `MirroredElemTypes` is also poly-kinded (`MirroredElemTypes = (B, C)`, `MirroredElemTypes[T] = (B, C)`, ...)

So if I wanted to do something further with a tuple `MirroredElemTypes` then the only option would be to have upper bound `AnyKind`

```
def foo[T <: AnyKind] = ???

foo[m.MirroredElemTypes]
```

Another example is `scala.quoted.Type` (thanks to @Max for pointing this out)

```
abstract class Type[T <: AnyKind]:
  type Underlying = T
```

https://contributors.scala-lang.org/t/proposal-to-add-kind-polymorphism-to-the-language/2958/16

Miles Sabin. Adding kind-polymorphism to the Scala programming language https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v6e7rYOXdcM

Comment: Dmytro, cheers. I've also found this article to explore the topic: https://contributors.scala-lang.org/t/proposal-to-add-kind-polymorphism-to-the-language/2958/16  and video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v6e7rYOXdcM

Answer (score 1):

for those who are interested in example.

I have found simple, yet clear one in [Dotty code base](https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty/blob/main/tests/pos/anykind.scala). See how `foo` takes polymorphic kind (any kind order) argument:

```
case class Bar[A](a: A)

trait Toto[A, B]

trait Foo[T <: AnyKind] {
  type Out;

  def id(t: Out): Out = t
}

object Foo {
  implicit def foo0[T]: Foo[T] {type Out = T} = new Foo[T] {
    type Out = T
  }

  implicit def foo1[T[_]]: Foo[T] {type Out = T[Any]} = new Foo[T] {
    type Out = T[Any]
  }

  implicit def foo2[T[_, _]]: Foo[T] {type Out = T[Any, Any]} = new Foo[T] {
    type Out = T[Any, Any]
  }
}

def foo[T <: AnyKind](implicit f: Foo[T]): f.type = f

foo[Int].id(23) == 23

foo[List].id(List[Any](1, 2, 3)) ==
  List(1, 2, 3)

foo[Map].id(Map[Any, Any](
  1 -> "toto",
  2 -> "tata",
  3 -> "tutu")) ==
  Map(
    1 -> "toto",
    2 -> "tata",
    3 -> "tutu")
```